# I'm getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) when I try to initialize a 1d array of 100 elements and use a pointer to fill it up

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, pointers, segmentation-fault

```
int main(void) {

  int x[100];
  int *myPtr;
  int j;
  myPtr = &(x[100]);

  for (j=0; j<100; j++) {
    *myPtr = j;
    myPtr ++;
  }

  printf("%d", *myPtr);

  return 0;
}
```

this is my code (so far)^
these are my directions:

1. Create a 1-dimensional integer array of size 100.
   a.  Using a pointer load the array with consecutive numbers from 0 to 99.
   b.  Using a pointer write out the array in ascending order.
   c.  Using a pointer write out the array in descending order.

Comment: `myPtr = &(x[100]);` -> `myPtr = &(x[0]);` or `myPtr = x;`

Comment: You're initializing `myPtr` to point beyond the end of the array.

Comment: `printf("%d", *myPtr);` is wrong as `myPtr` is now pointing past the end of the loop and also it doesn't  print out all the values as instructed. Reset the ptr back to the start of the array and use a loop to print each element out.

Answer (score 3):

The assignment in `myPtr = &(x[100]);` is incorrect: you make `myPtr` point to the end of the array, causing undefined behavior when you write there and beyond.

Change the assignment to `myPtr = x;` or `myPtr = &x[0];` and change the last statement to `printf("%d", *x);`

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x[100];
    int *myPtr;
    int j;

    myPtr = x;

    for (j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        *myPtr = j;
        myPtr++;
    }

    printf("x contains numbers from %d to %d\n", x[0], x[99]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fetching `x[100]` is undefined behavior.

```
myPtr = x;
for (j=0; j<100; j++)
  *myPtr++ = j;
```

To get the address of an array it's enough to evaluate `x`, which is the same as `&x`, the same as `&x[0]`, the same as `&0[x]`, the same as `&*(x+0)`.

Answer (score 2):

`x[100]` is a nonexistent element of the array `x` because the valid range of indices is `[0, 100)`.

So this statement

```
myPtr = &(x[100]);
```

sets the pointer `myPtr` to the address of the memory after the last element of the array. Dereferencing such a pointer invokes undefined behavior.

In the for loop that fills elements of the array you need a pointer that will pointer to the first element of the array `x`.

You can write

```
myPtr = &x[0];
```

Though it is simpler to write

```
myPtr = x;
```

because the array designator `x` used as an initializer is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

Your program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    int x[N];
  
    int value = 0;
    
    //  fill the array
    for ( int *myPtr = x; myPtr != x + N; ++myPtr )
    {
        *myPtr = value++;
    }
    
    //  output the array in the ascending order
    for ( const int *myPtr = x; myPtr != x + N; ++myPtr )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *myPtr );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    //  print the array in the descending order
    for ( const int *myPtr = x + N; myPtr != x;  )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *--myPtr );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

In the last two for loops there is used a pointer of the type `const int *` because within the loops elements of the array pointed to by the pointer are not being changed.